# Does minFileSizeForComp httpCompression attribute even work?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Has anyone got the

`<httpCompression minFileSizeForComp="XXX">`

setting to be honored by IIS 7.x?  The documentation here, http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression#005, states

> Optional uint attribute.
>   Specifies the minimum number of kilobytes a file must contain in order to use on-demand compression.
>   The default value for IIS 7.5 is 2700; for IIS 7.0 the default value was 256.

I think the documentation meant bytes and not kilobytes.  Could you imagine only HTTP compressing a response when it is 2.7 MB or greater?

I tried setting this value in the ApplicationHost.config and web.config with no affect.

Comment: The docs are definately wrong in regards to the number of bytes.  It is not kilobytes (1000's of bytes), but rather bytes.  You can confirm this by looking at the IIS 7.x Compression setting which has the following checkbox text:

"Only compress files larger than (in bytes):"

Answer (score 3):

IIS definitely respects the minFileSizeForComp setting. However if both dynamic and static compression is enabled then the small file may be compressed by dynamic compression. I wrote a blog post about it and shared the troubleshooting steps using the Failed Request Tracing rules and provided a solution / workaround for this behavior. Please find it in the following link:

Enlightining a mystery with Failed Request Tracing: does IIS not respect the minFileSizeForComp setting for static compression
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2016/05/23/iis-respects-minfilesizeforcomp-for-static-compression/

Hope that helps someone.

--
AMB

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift your content quality up –

Comment: I know this reply was from 2016, and its very enlightening. I need to filter Dynamic compression requests though, so if a dynamic request size is only a few bytes, to not compress it as it takes additional processing time and sometimes makes the request bigger than the original request. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm very late here, but I did some experiments around this issue and have determined that the value is measured in **kilobytes**. This seems insane, but it's true.

I made a blog post with a little more detail [here](http://blog.ymindustries.com/iis-compression-is-slightly-broken/).

EDIT: Hmm, the issue doesn't seem to be quite this simple. IIS seems to refuse to compress files below a certain size regardless of what is selected.

Comment: @foldinglettuce Yeah I deleted the blog post when I made my edit because I realised that what I'd thought was the answer wasn't at all. I don't think I ever solved this one, so you are on your own sorry.

Comment: I think I found the answer to my problem in applicationHost.config where you can turn compression configuration at the web.config level on or off.  Thanks for the reply

Comment: @foldinglettuce Glad you found an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Per @ahmetmithat's answer above, static files that are not compressed because they are smaller than the `minFileSizeForComp` threshold will be picked up by dynamic compression (if enabled) if their media type (`mimeType`) is added in both the `staticTypes` and `dynamicTypes`. One solution to this is to clear the `dynamicTypes` inherited from the machine configuration (`applicationHost.config`) and add just those types that you wish to compress dynamically. For example, if the only dynamic type you will be returning is JSON from your REST APIs, you could configure your `web.config` as follows:

```
<httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <clear />
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
  </dynamicTypes>
</httpCompression>
```